# Why is this topic too broad?

Tags: discussion

Well simply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598441/random-number-generator-distribution). I'm not going to explain it too much as I think it is clear from the topic already that it isn't broad at all.

What I ask for is a way to convert a continuous random distribution formula (whether it is normal, poisson, or my own formula) which has an integral of "1" on an interval, with the specific note that I mainly look for intervals which are bounded instead of infinite intervals.

As you see I'm asking for a very specific question: and I added "C#" too it to stress further that if there's a library (to prevent reinventing the wheel) I would use that, but mainly I ask for an algorithm to convert f(x) = 1 to g(x) distribution.

If it was off topic: so be it, then I ask again on math.stackexchange as it is in the boundary between mathematics and programming (though spawned by a game I wish to program).

Comment: Where is the code that you've tried?  You *have* tried to solve this yourself, right?  Show us that!  Right now, the question looks to be a pretty complicated problem, but there's nothing there that shows you've even made an attempt to solve it yourself.  Too broad is used because there are *countless* ways to solve it.  We have no idea how you're trying to go about it.

Answer (score 16):

Since no code is shown, any answer could take a million different approaches. We don't know where you are stuck precisely so this would require a sufficient answer to explain a multitude of aspects.

The question does not show any research effort nor an attempt at solving yourself. When you write something up yourself and you perform some tests to verify the distribution and notice it's off, that's when you come to Stack Overflow so we can look with you where the problem might be exactly.

Comment: I am stuck in converting a uniform random number to another distribution. What is the formula that I would apply to the output from the uniform RNG.

Comment: @paul23: http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate because you are not having a programming problem anymore.

Comment: I'm still wondering: as I very well know (it's always obvious) that you should take the integral and then the inverse. That's trivial stuff, however like I tried to explain for things such as the normal distribution this doesn't work anymore. And even for a quadratic distribution (Integral is a cubic function, which is not solveable easily). So I was also wondering: "how do other PROGRAMMERS" do this seemingly trivial but hard when looking into it. I know boost has it in their libraries.

Answer (score 9):

Commented:

> *You're "wondering", and "guessing this is more difficult" (sic). That's too broad. Recommendations go elsewhere and if you don't have a list of libraries you tried or an implementation that you're stuck with, you don't have a programming question.* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598441/random-number-generator-distribution#comment41831355_26598441)

Taking a random sample (hah!) from the question text:

> I guess this is more difficult as the function can't be integrated not has limits, but how would one do that?

I mean, it doesn't get much vaguer than "erm I'm feeling a bit anxious about my understanding of random distributions. Someone talk me out of it/hand me the magic potion/jell with my fear/tell me it's indeed very complex".

It doesn't get much more subjective than "I guess this is *more difficult*". Yes, it is definitely. Or not. Depending on, you know... ?

It does remind me of **["Has Anyone Really Been Far Even as Decided to Use Even Go Want to do Look More Like?"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/has-anyone-really-been-far-even-as-decided-to-use-even-go-want-to-do-look-more-like)**

Comment: Well as I said in another question: I am stuck at converting the f(x) = 0.75 - 0.75x^2 to a form for which I can add a uniformly distributed random input.

Comment: Wait. Did we have to go look at other questions by you? Does that include questions on [CS.SE] or [Math.SE]? Oh, and Ask Yahoo!, maybe.

Comment: I meant another comment here -.-

Comment: @paul23 oh. Even so. It doesn't show where in the implementation you might be stuck (that would also help us understand whatever you could have meant by `converting [...] to a form for which I can add a uniformly distributed random input` (I can add whatever input to whatever function I have)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't asked a specific question that is an obstacle to your implementation.

Show your code, discuss the issue and people would answer it.

It is too-broad because it can be implemented in many ways where each way has its own pros and cons.